# Load extends after blocks

Tags: twig

So I have been working with twig now, and I use a function manner to render all of my html. My question is, is there a way to render the blocks (with functions) first, and then the {% extends X %} afterwards?

example:

```
   {% extends 'base.html.twig' %}
    {% block body %}
        {{ resource('script', 'google.com') }}
    {% endblock %}
```

I would want the resource function to trigger, before the file is extended, in some way.

Reason why:
In the base I define another function which loads a head with a base configuration, it also gives easy options to load certain libraries such as bootstrap etc. But I want the user able to later, externally in a body add more resources and make them pop up in the head instead of in the body. I can give more code if needed but I think this will suffice since this is more a twig question than a php question.

Comment: Note: Without the need of an extra {% block tag %}

Comment: What exactly is the problem with defining a new block for the scripts and using that block in the child template instead?

Comment: Because i'm writing a very big twig extension right now and I find the blocks ugly, it's meant to be a short way to write html, and needing to open a block, then define the resource and then close is way more than just the one liner. Additionally, I have the nodejs version all ready to go and there it DOES work with the one-liner, and I'd like my syntax to be consistent.

Comment: Use the plugin I mention in this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/45498998/446594)